# Perform get request in Spring using a header

Tags: junit, spring-security

I'm writing a unit test that test my WebSecurity configuration.

Here is my Test :

```
@Test
public void access_to_a_protected_url_with_good_credentials_return_ok() throws Exception {
    String accessToken = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:password").getBytes());

    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get("/protected")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + accessToken))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this test without passing the authorization token using the way I'm doing ?

Answer (score 0):

One way, similar to yours is to build the request using `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`:

```
@Test
public void access_to_a_protected_url_with_good_credentials_return_ok() throws Exception {
    String accessToken = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:password").getBytes());

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockReqBuilder = get("/protected").headers(httpHeaders);

    ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(mockReqBuilder);
    actions.andExpect(status().isOk());        

}
```

Did I understand your question correctly?